# String processing very slow in new Android version(4.3)

Tags: android

I am trying to break a String into multiple pages. The string contains a story(hence a bit long one) and I need to load this into an ArrayList of Strings which will be displayed as various pages.

Below is the method in my code which takes in the long string and breaks it into pages and loads the ArrayList of Strings. My problem is that this works pretty fast in Android 3.2. But in my another phone which is 4.3, it loads very slow(say it takes about 10 seconds for what works in 2 seconds in 3.2 one). Below is my code. Can anyone of you please suggest any improvements here in the code which can make it work faster in the new version. Not sure why should new version process slower than the old one.

```
TextView contentTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewStory1);
String contentString;
TextPaint tp = contentTextView.getPaint();
String[] pages;
int totalPages=0;
ArrayList<String> pagesArray = new ArrayList<String>();
public void loadStory(String storyName){

    //initialize variables
    numCharsLine=0;
    contentString = getStringFromTxtFile(storyName);

    int linesInOnePage = getLinesInPage();//get how many lines will be displayed in one page
    //load story into arraylist pagesArray
    while (contentString != null && contentString.length() != 0) 
    {
        totalPages ++;
        int numChars = 0;
        int lineCount = 0;

        while ((lineCount < linesInOnePage) && (numChars < contentString.length())) {

            numCharsLine = tp.breakText(contentString.substring(numChars), true, pageWidth, null);

            numChars = numChars + numCharsLine;
            lineCount ++;
        }
        // retrieve the String to be displayed in pagesArray
        String toBeDisplayed = contentString.substring(0, numChars);
        contentString = contentString.substring(numChars);
        pagesArray.add(toBeDisplayed);
        numChars = 0;
        lineCount = 0;
    }
    //get the pagecount and reset pageNumber to current page
    totalPages=pagesArray.size();
    pages = new String[pagesArray.size()];
    pages = pagesArray.toArray(pages);  
}
```

Also below is the method for loading the contents of text file into the string

```
    public String getStringFromTxtFile(String fileName) {

    try {
         InputStream is = getAssets().open(fileName+".txt");
         int size = is.available();
         byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
         is.read(buffer);
         is.close();

         return new String(buffer);

         }
         catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
         } 
}
```

Comment: Forgive me for being honest.  This code is unreadable, hard to understand, difficult to maintain and horribly inefficient. I shudder to think about how many strings are created inside that loop. There is probably a much better solution to achieve what you want to do. To help, please explain where this story comes from, how it's formatted and laid out and how you define what a "page" is.

Comment: I have edited my code to make it look simpler. The complexity involved was because of the fact that I had to insert linebreaks to make sure it exactly fits the screen. The default android textpaint was not word warpping to fit screen. The edited code has all the string operations intact, but some int related operations are out.

Comment: Thanks to Simon's compliments above, I figured out a much efficient way to display a long string across number of pages. 
-I display the long text into the text view and disable scrolling
-I then find out the lines in the layout and lines on single screen, hence I know how many screens(pages) will the long string span across
-Then whenever user clicks a button to go to next page or swipes screen to go to the next page then I use TexView.scrollTo() function to move to number of lines(as many on a screen) forward. So it becomes as good as moving to next page.

Answer (score 0):

For now you are reading whole file to string, then split this string into lines and process it.

I would suggest you to union reading text from file and processing it line by line.

for example, using class LineNumberReader or BufferedReader:

```
BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("my/file/path"));
String line;
while ((line = bis.readLine()) != null) {
    processLine(line); //process current line
}
```

therefore you don't have to do so many concat and substring actions.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs but this will not help I guess as I will anyway have to process each line further with more string operations to insert a line break based on the screen width and further to insert pagebreak when number of lines exceed page height. Also I have updated my code above to add the txt file reading method as well.