# How to Paginate TextView in Android?

Tags: android, pagination, textview

I am using this class `PageSplitter` provided by stackoverflow user `mixel` for **pagination of textview** ([gist link](https://gist.github.com/mxl/7648303))

```
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.StyleSpan;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PageSplitter {
    private final int pageWidth;
    private final int pageHeight;
    private final float lineSpacingMultiplier;
    private final int lineSpacingExtra;
    private final List<CharSequence> pages = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
    private SpannableStringBuilder currentLine = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    private SpannableStringBuilder currentPage = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    private int currentLineHeight;
    private int pageContentHeight;
    private int currentLineWidth;
    private int textLineHeight;

    public PageSplitter(int pageWidth, int pageHeight, float lineSpacingMultiplier, int lineSpacingExtra) {
        this.pageWidth = pageWidth;
        this.pageHeight = pageHeight;
        this.lineSpacingMultiplier = lineSpacingMultiplier;
        this.lineSpacingExtra = lineSpacingExtra;
    }

    public void append(String text, TextPaint textPaint) {
        textLineHeight = (int) Math.ceil(textPaint.getFontMetrics(null) * lineSpacingMultiplier + lineSpacingExtra);
        String[] paragraphs = text.split("\n", -1);
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < paragraphs.length - 1; i++) {
            appendText(paragraphs[i], textPaint);
            appendNewLine();
        }
        appendText(paragraphs[i], textPaint);
    }

    private void appendText(String text, TextPaint textPaint) {
        String[] words = text.split(" ", -1);
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) {
            appendWord(words[i] + " ", textPaint);
        }
        appendWord(words[i], textPaint);
    }

    private void appendNewLine() {
        currentLine.append("\n");
        checkForPageEnd();
        appendLineToPage(textLineHeight);
    }

    private void checkForPageEnd() {
        if (pageContentHeight + currentLineHeight > pageHeight) {
            pages.add(currentPage);
            currentPage = new SpannableStringBuilder();
            pageContentHeight = 0;
        }
    }

    private void appendWord(String appendedText, TextPaint textPaint) {
        int textWidth = (int) Math.ceil(textPaint.measureText(appendedText));
        if (currentLineWidth + textWidth >= pageWidth) {
            checkForPageEnd();
            appendLineToPage(textLineHeight);
        }
        appendTextToLine(appendedText, textPaint, textWidth);
    }

    private void appendLineToPage(int textLineHeight) {
        currentPage.append(currentLine);
        pageContentHeight += currentLineHeight;

        currentLine = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        currentLineHeight = textLineHeight;
        currentLineWidth = 0;
    }

    private void appendTextToLine(String appendedText, TextPaint textPaint, int textWidth) {
        currentLineHeight = Math.max(currentLineHeight, textLineHeight);
        currentLine.append(renderToSpannable(appendedText, textPaint));
        currentLineWidth += textWidth;
    }

    public List<CharSequence> getPages() {
        List<CharSequence> copyPages = new ArrayList<CharSequence>(pages);
        SpannableStringBuilder lastPage = new SpannableStringBuilder(currentPage);
        if (pageContentHeight + currentLineHeight > pageHeight) {
            copyPages.add(lastPage);
            lastPage = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        }
        lastPage.append(currentLine);
        copyPages.add(lastPage);
        return copyPages;
    }

    private SpannableString renderToSpannable(String text, TextPaint textPaint) {
        SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(text);

        if (textPaint.isFakeBoldText()) {
            spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, spannable.length(), 0);
        }
        return spannable;
    }
}
```

But, when I use it like following - (as mentioned by the same user in answer to one similar question on stackoverflow itself - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204348/how-to-break-styled-text-into-pages-in-android))

```
ViewPager pageView = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pages);
PageSplitter pageSplitter = new PageSplitter(pageView.getWidth(), pageView.getHeight(), 1, 0);
TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
textPaint.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size));
pageSplitter.append(TestString, textPaint);
pageView.setAdapter(new TextPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), pageSplitter.getPages()));
```

it breaks the the string into words, and each word is displayed on separate screen of viewpager, instead of breaking string into screen-fit length (or 1st splitting upto words level, then concatenating to a screen fit length). I am trying to find out, **how to make it work or what is wrong in this** for more than 7 days, but I could not get a single success.

Addition info -

TextPagerAdapter:

```
public class TextPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<CharSequence> pageTexts;

    public TextPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<CharSequence> pageTexts) {
        super(fm);
        this.pageTexts = pageTexts;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return PageFragment.newInstance(pageTexts.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pageTexts.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of that PageSplitter use StaticLayout class

Comment: please did you find the solution to this problem?