# Paginate text based on rendered text size

Tags: android, pdf, pagination, textview

**Background:** I want to render text into a PDF, using the [PDFDocument](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html) framework. This framework requires you to do pagination manually. The text will be multiple pages in length, so I need to split the text once it exceeds the page size

**Problem:** Each page is 540x720px** in size. So basically, I need to figure out how to split a long string at each point that it would fill a 540x720px `TextView`.

**Potential Hack:** Overriding the onMeasure method of the TextView, and using a loop to continuously add text and re-measure until it exceeds 720px length

Is there a better solution to this?

**540x720px based on 8.5x11" paper, 0.5" margins, 72dpi

Answer (score 0):

A `PageSplitter` can be used as a solution to this problem. The class can be found in the answer found below

[How to break styled text into pages in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204348/how-to-break-styled-text-into-pages-in-android)