# Android: how to determine last fully visible letter in TextView?

Tags: android, string, view, textview, spannablestring

I am trying to build a book reader. And now I am having a long text which fills up the entire screen and even some of the text is out of screen. I want to know how to find the last letter that is fully visible in screen so that I can split text into pages.

For example, all lines before

> "Bad news, Vernon," she said......

are fully visible text, and remaining text has to be moved to another page.

[image]

Like this(another page of text starts with "Bad news")

[image]

Here is the layout that I used in above example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="...some text..." />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you are trying to achieve page splinting
please check this out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204348/how-to-break-styled-text-into-pages-in-android

Comment: I have tried the sample app provided from argando's link and it seems working as what I want

Answer (score 1):

I think that predicting where a text is going to end would be difficult/impossible unless you were using a monospaced font, e.g. Courier.  But instead of taking this approach, an alternative I can suggest is to simply deliver a constant number of characters for each page of your book reader.  Yes, this means that with a non monospaced font you won't know the exact number of lines to be rendered.  However, the number of lines taken up should fall within a fairly tight range, and most likely would not be perceptible to the user.

You can use a `ScrollView` here, which would contain the actual `TextView` holding the text for each page.  Here is a skeleton of what that might look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="...some text..." />
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Using a `ScrollView`, the user can then simply drag up and down to catch any content which might not fit into a single screen.  Again, this frees you from having to worry about delivering an exact amount of content.

Comment: I know using ScrollView with TextView is an easy approach for display long text but still it is not a page-splitting approach

Comment: @Season What I'm saying is to use a scroll view and then you don't need to worry about "page-splitting."  Most readers probably follow this approach.