# How to split an HTML text into screens?

Tags: android, html, android-viewpager

I have HTML text as that

```
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>I am normal</p>


<p><b>This text is bold</b></p>
<p><i>This text is italic</i></p>
<p>This is<sub> subscript</sub> and <sup>superscript</sup></p>
```

and it should appear like that

---

## This is a heading

This is a paragraph.

I am normal

**This text is bold**

*This text is italic*

This is <sub>subscript</sub> and <sup>superscript</sup>

---

How can I split the whole text into screens Based on screen width and height and with the HTML style?

I tried this answer 
[How to break styled text into pages in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204348/how-to-break-styled-text-into-pages-in-android)
but the HTML style not saved

Is there any library or code can do this?

Comment: [Paginating text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32096884/3290339). However keep in mind that only a limited set of `html` tags is supported by Android.

Answer (score 0):

Full HTML can be rendered just in `WebViews`, to have screen-related text dimensions you can use a custom styled `TextView` nested in a layout like `RelativeLayout`, referencing views width and height in dimens.xml (so you can adopt different paddings and dimensions for small and large devices)